# How to revalidate all fields in a form generated using ng-repeat when one field changes

Tags: angularjs

I've a form with multiple input fields generate using ng-repeat.
I've created a custom validation which checks that none of the fields should have duplicate value.
So if field1 has value ABC, and if user types ABC in field2, it displays error.
But if user changes value of field1 to XYZ, error still remains on field2 since it is not re-validated.

What is the best way to validate all the fields in a form generated using ng-repeat.

Here's what the code looks like

```
<div ng-form name="editConfigNameForm">
<input 
    ng-repeat='config in configs'
    type="text" 
    ng-model="config.newName" 
    name="configName"
/>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's the code that isn't working as expected? Question is far too broad simply asking .. *"what is best way"*

Comment: Sorry. Added the code.

Comment: @charlietfl its a custom validator. And it has nothing to do with the question I've asked. 

Question is about validating all the other fields in a form when one of the fields changes.

Comment: I realize that...and this whole question revolves around it not working properly. If you want help fixing it you need to post the code. That's how the site works

Comment: Updated the main code. 

Custom validator has a lot of dependencies.
I will have to include all those dependencies as well.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient, but one method could be to give each field in the form an id that corresponds to the field and the form (I.e. id="field1form(ng-repeat key) and id="field2form(ng-repeat key).

Create a method called by ng-change that takes the field id as a parameter, determine the form number (ng-repeat key) and check the opposing field.

This would allow you to differentiate between the forms and fields as they're created and then have the id's able to function as parameters for your check method.

Comment: `scope.revalidateColumnNames = function(editConfigNameForm, length){
        for(var i = 0; i <length; i++){
                editConfigNameForm['configName_'+ i].$validate();
        }
                    
};` 

Tried doing the same but it throws error. Undefined method $validate.

Comment: When using validate you only need the form name (it will validate all fields). Assuming "editConfigNameForm" is your form name, should look like this:  `editConfigNameForm.$ validate()`  This could also trigger the submit check if true.